# selenium python crash when using try/except condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

**i'm trying make auto follow to tiktok with selenium, but i got a problem when i say if found Button: "Follow" Click it and go back, but if didn't find it go back..**

```
comment1 = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#app > div.tiktok-19fglm-DivBodyContainer.etsvyce0 > a')
comment1.click()
time.sleep(7)
try:
    follow = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#app > div.tiktok-ywuvyb-DivBodyContainer.etsvyce0 > div.tiktok-1h3j14u-DivFollowButtonWrapper.e143oaad4')
    follow.click()
    driver.back()
except:
    driver.back()
comments.click()
```

**but for sorry i have a this problem**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/idlelib/run.py", line 559, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "/home/eslammustafa/Desktop/PY Projects/0undetectable tiktok login.py", line 142, in <module>
    comments.click()
  File "/home/eslammustafa/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 81, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "/home/eslammustafa/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 710, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/home/eslammustafa/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 424, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/eslammustafa/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=98.0.4758.102)
Stacktrace:
#0 0x557988df4b33 <unknown>
#1 0x5579888bd6d8 <unknown>
#2 0x5579888c055c <unknown>
#3 0x5579888c0356 <unknown>
#4 0x5579888c060c <unknown>
#5 0x5579888f526f <unknown>
#6 0x5579888e85d6 <unknown>
#7 0x557988911062 <unknown>
#8 0x5579888e7fa3 <unknown>
#9 0x55798891116e <unknown>
#10 0x5579889242fb <unknown>
#11 0x557988910f53 <unknown>
#12 0x5579888e6a0a <unknown>
#13 0x5579888e7ad5 <unknown>
#14 0x557988e262fd <unknown>
#15 0x557988e3f4bb <unknown>
#16 0x557988e280d5 <unknown>
#17 0x557988e40145 <unknown>
#18 0x557988e1baaf <unknown>
#19 0x557988e5cba8 <unknown>
#20 0x557988e5cd28 <unknown>
#21 0x557988e7748d <unknown>
#22 0x7fd141ca8609 <unknown>
```

Comment: The exception you posted occurs when you call _comments.click()_. But in your code snippet you don't show how _comments_ is defined. Please specify exactly what you are doing and what you want to achieve.

Comment: Selenium gives references to elements in browser memory - when you load new page then it removes elements from memory and when you go back to previous page then these elements can be in different place in memory and references are useless - and this gives your message `"stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document"`. You have to use `find_element` again, or first you should get all URLS as text, next change pages and go back, and later use `get(url)` instead of `click()`. But when you have URLS then you don't have to go back but use  directly `get(url)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to search comments element again using find element once you returned to previous page
I'm assuming after driver.back() you want to click on comment1 then your code should looks like

```
comment1 = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#app > div.tiktok-19fglm-DivBodyContainer.etsvyce0 > a')
comment1.click()
time.sleep(7)
try:
    follow = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#app > div.tiktok-ywuvyb-DivBodyContainer.etsvyce0 > div.tiktok-1h3j14u-DivFollowButtonWrapper.e143oaad4')
    follow.click()
    driver.back()
except:
    driver.back()
comment1 = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#app > div.tiktok-19fglm-DivBodyContainer.etsvyce0 > a')
comment1.click()
```

Comment: I think this is not the answer, please add this as a comment.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).